Postgresql Replication
I have a table in production whose structure I want to modify. I can ALTER the table to add column but the column gets added at the end, may be the order may not matter. But at least visually I see it as the last column. The table was created at the last release and it was empty. So, I thought of dropping it & re-creating it in my flyway script. But it led to build failure as the database replication is on in production. How to deal with it? Database is PostgreSQL. At this point of time, I do not have information about scheme of replication as the production environment is with client.

There is too little information. Are you using streaming replication or logical replication? Please describe the failure in great detail, including the exact error messages. Please don't add that information as a comment, but [edit] the question.

Use ALTER TABLE to add the new column, even if it appears at the end—this is the safest method in a replicated environment.

That we have already done. But just for academic interest, can we use DROP TABLE table_name
CASCADE;

Technically, you can execute DROP TABLE ... CASCADE; without an issue in a non-replicated or development environment. However, in production environments with replication enabled, it should be avoided unless you fully understand the replication setup and the consequences of dropping and re-creating tables. Always ensure that the drop is coordinated during a maintenance window with proper checks in place to ensure replication consistency.
For structural changes, the safe route is always to use ALTER TABLE instead of dropping and recreating a table, especially in production settings.
